# How to check if memcache is expired

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am storing values for in a collection and setting the expiration date to one day from today:

```
mservice.put("myList", listValues, Expiration.onDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 86400000)));
```

When the cache expires when I request this List using:

```
mservice.get("myList");
```

Will the returned value be empty?

I want to refresh the cache once per day and need a way to check if the cache is expired. If it is expired then repopulate the cache. Is method described above the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_get says, the return-value will be *None* (not an empty list) if the key isn't in the cache anymore. So yes, if your call returns None, you need to refresh it.

Comment: T. Steinrücken im using java implementation. None is not supported in java but it may use null in its place if the object is expired.